# Loading markers on google maps dynamically on map move/drag/pan

Tags: google-maps

I need to display a set of markers on a google map. In addition, I need to show additional markers, loaded dynamically, when the user pans the maps.

The number of markers could be in thousands, out of which 30-50 need to be displayed initially. Other markers need to be loaded and displayed only when user pans over an area that contains markers. I thought about using marker managers but i am not sure if markers can be fed to the marker manager dynamically. I want something more like [this](http://www.panoramio.com/map/#lt=47.638560&ln=-122.302551&z=4&k=2&a=1&tab=1) map. Notice how images load when you pan the map and garbage-collected when you pan away.

Marker clustering is not important but might be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am doing this with clustering on a dataset of several thousand markers.  This is how I'm doing it:  When the 'moveend' event is fired, I get the bounds of the map and send an ajax request to the server.  I get the markers from your DB which are in the bounds and send them back to the client.  If you have questions about a specific part of the process, just let me know.

Also, with the Marker Manager, I believe that you can add markers dynamically.

Comment: Got it! I wonder if it is possible to use marker manager with AJAX instead of writing my own moveend implementation? Markermanager takes care of few others chores I think.

Comment: The only drawback to Marker Manager is that it doesn't cluster.  You just tell it which markers you want to be visible at which zoom, and it shows/hides them as you move around.

Comment: Clustering is not required, I am asked to lock the zoom and show all markers. Problem solved!

Comment: how do you prevent the markers that have already been loaded from being loaded again as part of the ajax request?